# C++ modules might have a core dump issue

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-modules

## Source Code

hello.cpp

```cpp
module;

import <filesystem>;
import <iostream>;

export module hello;

export void fun()
{
        std::cout << "Hello, GCC " << __GNUC__ << '.' << __GNUC_MINOR__ << '.' << __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ << '!' << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Hello, CXX " << __cplusplus << '!' << std::endl;
        std::cout << "PWD: " << std::filesystem::current_path() << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
import hello;

int main()
{
        fun();
        return 0;
}
```

## Platform

- OS: Linux
- distribution: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- architecture: x86_64 & aarch64 (both tested)
- GCC: 11.3.0 & 14.0.0 (both tested)

## Compilation Commands

```bash
g++-14 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -x c++-system-header filesystem iostream
g++-14 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -Wall -Wextra -pedantic hello.cpp main.cpp -o module-test-g++-14

g++-11 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c -x c++-system-header filesystem iostream
g++-11 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -Wall -Wextra -pedantic hello.cpp main.cpp -o module-test-g++-11
```

## Execution Results

The results are similar for different architectures and GCC versions. All of them result in a core dump issue.

```bash
user@host:~/tmp$ ./module-test-g++-14 
Hello, GCC 14.0.0!
Hello, CXX 202302!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

user@host:~/tmp$ ./module-test-g++-11 
Hello, GCC 11.3.0!
Hello, CXX 202100!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

## Debugging

It seems that the problem is due to an internal allocation failure.

```
(gdb) 
298           _M_get_allocator() const
(gdb) 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::max_size (this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:932
932           { return (_Alloc_traits::max_size(_M_get_allocator()) - 1) / 2; }
(gdb) 

std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::max_size (__a=...) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:552
552             return size_t(-1) / sizeof(value_type);
(gdb) 
547           max_size(const allocator_type& __a __attribute__((__unused__))) noexcept
(gdb) 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::max_size (this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:932
932           { return (_Alloc_traits::max_size(_M_get_allocator()) - 1) / 2; }
(gdb) 
931           max_size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
(gdb) 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create (this=0x7fffffffdf40, __capacity=@0x7fffffffddd0: 93824992338720, __old_capacity=0) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:137
137           if (__capacity > max_size())
(gdb) 
143           if (__capacity > __old_capacity && __capacity < 2 * __old_capacity)
(gdb) 
153           return _Alloc_traits::allocate(_M_get_allocator(), __capacity + 1);
(gdb) 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_get_allocator (this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:295
295           { return _M_dataplus; }
(gdb) 
294           _M_get_allocator()
(gdb) 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create (this=0x7fffffffdf40, __capacity=@0x7fffffffddd0: 93824992338720, __old_capacity=0) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.tcc:153
153           return _Alloc_traits::allocate(_M_get_allocator(), __capacity + 1);
(gdb) 
std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::allocate (__a=..., __n=93824992338721) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/alloc_traits.h:464
464           { return __a.allocate(__n); }
(gdb) 
std::allocator<char>::allocate (__n=93824992338721, this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocator.h:182
182             if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
(gdb) 
std::is_constant_evaluated () at /usr/include/c++/11/type_traits:3419
3419      { return __builtin_is_constant_evaluated(); }
(gdb) 
3418      is_constant_evaluated() noexcept
(gdb) 
std::allocator<char>::allocate (__n=93824992338721, this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /usr/include/c++/11/bits/allocator.h:182
182             if (std::is_constant_evaluated())
(gdb) 
185             return __allocator_base<_Tp>::allocate(__n, 0);
(gdb) 
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::allocate (this=0x7fffffffdf40, __n=93824992338721) at /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:111
111             if (__builtin_expect(__n > this->_M_max_size(), false))
(gdb) 
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::_M_max_size (this=0x7fffffffdf40) at /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:200
200             return std::size_t(__PTRDIFF_MAX__) / sizeof(_Tp);
(gdb) 
197           _M_max_size() const _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
(gdb) 
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::allocate (this=0x7fffffffdf40, __n=93824992338721) at /usr/include/c++/11/ext/new_allocator.h:111
111             if (__builtin_expect(__n > this->_M_max_size(), false))
(gdb) 
127             return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
(gdb) 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140737348187968) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
44      ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
```

## Question

Is there anything wrong with my compilation commands? Or is this a bug of GCC?

- If it's my fault, please tell me how to compile the code.
- If it's a GCC's bug, I will report it to [the official website](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/).

Comment: ¿Why are there two build commands? ¿Is result of the first command even used?  ¿Have you tried a single command like `g++-14 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -Wall -Wextra -pedantic hello.cpp main.cpp -o module-test-g++-14 -x c++-system-header filesystem iostream`

Comment: The header units should be specified before the source files that import them. And the executable created by `g++-14 -std=c++23 -fmodules-ts -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -x c++-system-header filesystem iostream -x c++ hello.cpp main.cpp -o module-test-g++-14` still has a core dump issue.

Comment: @ShuangchengNi: If it works if you `#include` the headers instead of importing them as header units, then it's a problem with GCC's standard library header unit functionality.